# How to add layout from xml to Extended FrameLayout Android?

Tags: android, layout, user-interface, view

I have a custom class called `NoteView` that extends `FrameLayout`.  Previously, I had just been using the stock `LinearLayout` and have an XML layout built already that I want to reuse by adding that entire hierarchy (with some other overlay views which is why I needed framelayout) to the `NoteView`.

The problem is I can't figure out how to inflate the XML and add it to the `NoteView` from within the `NoteView` Class.  I can add it after initialization is complete, but I want to be able to be able to inflate that hierarchy and add it automatically when my `NoteView` is either instantiated or inflated from XML.

How can I populate my extended `FrameLayout` with a layout from XML by adding it from within the `NoteView` class itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `LayoutInflater`

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout myView = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
frameLayout.addChild(myView);
```

Have a look at the documentation for `LayoutInflater` here: http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work at first.  I just realized though that I was casting my top level view to the wrong class which was causing it to crash.  This whole question is a red herring. :)

Comment: `FrameLayout` doesn't have `addChild(...)` method. Did you mean `addView(View child)`?

Comment: Of course it called addView(View child). In direct extended class (extends FrameLayout) you can add it in the constructor: this.addView(myView)